# Save correctly in PDF to Drive a Google Sheet

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, attachment, urlfetch

I am developing a script under Sheet allowing:

- send an email with a PDF copy of the sheet attached
- save this sheet in PDF in my Drive (defined with the id of the folder)

I succeeded without any problem for the first part of the script. For the second part, I also succeeded in making this backup. However, the information present in this one does not suit me. Indeed, the images are not transferred in the file (I have "cellimage" which appears instead) and the data do not correspond to those present in my Sheet. Indeed, they are rounded to 3 digits after the comma in my sheet while in the backup, there is no rounding.

I would have liked to have the same file as the one that is attached to the email. I searched hard but I could not find a code to save my attachment in the drive.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15wXx_IiLiPEJbM_jYgEHwcKk0-Uz6rpGcrWyrDZb2Tc/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to the file.

Here is the function that allows you to send the mail:

```
function envoiMail() {
  // Déclaration des constantes
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('SYNTHESE');

  // Déclaration des variables
  var semaine = feuille.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var annee = feuille.getRange('B4').getValue();

  var auditeurMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split('@');
  var auditeurNomPrenom = auditeurMail[0].split('.');
  var auditeurPrenom = majString(auditeurNomPrenom[0]);
  var auditeurNom = majString(auditeurNomPrenom[1]);
  var signature = auditeurPrenom+' '+auditeurNom;

  var sujet = 'test ' + semaine + ' (' + annee +')';
  var corpsDuMail = '<p>Bonjour,</p>'
  + '<p> Veuillez trouver ci-joint le test de la semaine ' + semaine + '-'+annee+'.</b></p><br>'
  + '</p>Bonne réception,</p>'
  + signature;

 // Pièce jointe
 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", classeur.getId());
 var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=true' + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' 
            + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=false' + '&gid=';
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 var pdfMarge = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + feuille.getSheetId(),{headers : {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token }}).getBlob().setName("Marge_previsionnelle_S"+semaine+"_"+annee+".pdf");


 // Fonction permettant d'envoyer le mail
 MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", sujet, corpsDuMail, {
 htmlBody : corpsDuMail,
 attachments : [pdfMarge]
 });

 // Pop-up pour informer que l'envoi de mails s'est déroulé correctement
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Le mail a bien été envoyé aux personnes concernées !");
}

// Fonction permettant de mettre en majuscule la première lettre de la chaîne de caractère
function majString(a){
   return (a+'').charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1);
 }
```

And here is the function that allows me to archive my sheet in my drive:

```
function sauvegardeDrive() {
  // Déclaration des variables et constantes
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('SYNTHESE');
  var sheetName = "SYNTHESE";
  var folderID = "1sRkfgLO8C4ABcrzPBonGPJm3emzWD3Ct";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var semaine = feuille.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var annee = feuille.getRange('B4').getValue();
  var pdfName = "test"+semaine+"_"+annee+".pdf";

  //Copie de l'ensemble du Sheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("copieFichier", folder));

 //Suppression des onglets inutiles
 var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
 for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
   }
 }
 var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; 
 var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
 var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
 var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
 destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

 //Sauvegarde en pdf
 var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
 var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

 //Suppression du Sheet temporaire
 DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out (or delete) these lines in `sauvegardeDrive()` function:

```
  // var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  // var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  // var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  // var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  // destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
```

You don't need them. You already copied the sheet, you don't need to copy the sheet data again.

**Update**

If your sheet contains referenced date, you can convert it into static date if you add these two lines before the loop that removes another sheets (above the comment '//Suppression des onglets inutiles'):

```
var range = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('SYNTHESE').getDataRange(); 
range.setValues(range.getDisplayValues());
```

**Update 2**

If the mail script works fine for you, you can just use the same part of the code for saving the sheet. Try this hew function `sauvegardeDrive()`:

```
function sauvegardeDrive() {
  // Déclaration des variables et constantes
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('SYNTHESE');
  var sheetName = "SYNTHESE";
  var folderID = "1gZEWeG4XzZDuEqDDWKaMoVolMmeLWDRI";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var semaine = feuille.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var annee = feuille.getRange('B4').getValue();
  var pdfName = "test"+semaine+"_"+annee+".pdf";

  // Pièce jointe -- this part is stealed from envoiMail() function
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", classeur.getId());
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=true' + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' 
              + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=false' + '&gid=';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var pdfMarge = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + feuille.getSheetId(),{headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token }}).getBlob().setName(pdfName);

  folder.createFile(pdfMarge);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend, it works well ! However, if my sheet file contains multiple tabs, it will save all of them in my pdf. Do you know a way around this please?

Comment: Did you try? Your script removes all sheets but 'SYNTHESE' from the copy before making a PDF. There is is the loop after the comment `//Suppression des onglets inutiles` . It does exactly this. I just tired to add a couple sheets, run the script and I see no these extra sheets in the result PDF.

Comment: Spreadsheet with extra tabs: https://imgur.com/uSLaVQk.png PDF: https://imgur.com/XLY5njo.png

Comment: Yes, it works for the test file I sent you, I agree. I forgot to mention, however, and I apologize, that the real file fetches the data thanks to SEARCHV. And since I'm creating a copy, I get #REF! instead of my results (the data is not processed and the file doesn't have the authorization to access this sheet). I'm really sorry I forgot to mention this before, I didn't think it was going to have an impact on the result (I'm a beginner in scripting)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Try my update. I think it will preserve all referenced data inside the spreadsheet. If you have references between spreadsheets (not between sheets) it may require additional actions.

Comment: Sorry, I certainly misspoke Yuri. The final file that will host the script is quite complex. Indeed, it will look for data from tabs of the sheet via SEARCHV. And these tabs will themselves retrieve data from other sheets via IMPORTRANGE. 
As far as the SEARCHV is concerned, the code you gave me works perfectly.
However, the data coming from the IMPORTRANGE are not brought back because the copy of the sheet does not have the authorizations to access these files.
I hope that these explanations will be clearer for you. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It is possible that the code may not be suitable for what I want to do. And I was wondering if it was possible to save the attachment from the sendEmail function directly to the Drive. 
All the information is filled in this one since it is not a copy.

Comment: Let try one more thing. Revert your old script `sauvegardeDrive()` and try to change there just one line:  `var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();` by ` var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();` The `getDispayValues()`. As for if there is a way to save some attached PDF from your sent mail, I'm sure it's possible as well. So you always have the last resort.